# Trapping downloads within Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download

I've looked around and haven't been able to find anything that will allow me to detect when a download is finished within Chrome.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to better "sort" my downloads once they are downloaded, automatically based on various criteria.

I've tried setting up a listener with: webRequest.onCompleted and while that seems to work for most resources (images, .ico, etc), I can't get it to trap a .ZIP or .EXE file download.  I'm not sure why it won't, but it'll work for other resources without a problem.

I haven't set a filter on it so it should (as far as I know) be pulling in all resources and checking them for the specified extensions.  I know that might not be the best way to do check, but I haven't found a better one yet.

Looking at the experimental downloads API, that doesn't seem to do what I want either as that mostly just initiates a download, which isn't what I am trying to do.

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: Any reason you don't just get the download folder, and monitor it for file changes (i.e. Download completion to that folder)? I imagine it'd be trivial to see if the file is complete, as it'll be present and I believe partially download files have .part attached to them.

Comment: I could do that, but there'd be no real way to sort them then.  I could already sort them by extension, etc.  What I want to do is sort them by the domain I downloaded them from.

Comment: Possibly you could make it manipulate the save location, so that it pretends you told it to save somewhere new?

Comment: @TroyJ I presume you mean sort them in the sense you want to group them? More specifically, by their originating domain? If that's the case, monitor the download folder and then check the extended attribute of the file in question for the download URL. See: http://superuser.com/questions/214934/how-can-mac-os-x-save-details-about-the-url-from-which-a-file-has-been-downloade

Comment: @Louis, that's something I had no idea about.  I think that will end up solving the issue and I'll just have to write an app that'll watch the folder and do what needs to be done.  Ultimately, probably better than having to try and Javascript it anyway. =)  Thanks much, I'll give that route a try and see how it goes.

Comment: After further researching this last idea of using the kMDItemWhereFroms extended file attribute, it appears this is only available on the MACOS version of Chrome (as far as I can tell).  I'm still looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't seen an extension for this, but when you think about it this kind of makes sense.  It almost seems like something that should be native to the browser...I guess it does give you the most recent downloads though and that is relevant to your current task.  Anyways, thought I would mention that there is an experimental api that allows interaction with the native download interactions.  This may be a reference needed in getting the extension cooking.  Good luck

Link to Experimental API:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.downloads.html